# How do you buy AWS EBS like an RI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, reserved-instances

I have bought and am using a reserved instance however I still get monthly bills for the EBS.

Question is how do I make a similar single payment for the volume as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't thnk this is possible.

[From the official site](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prepay-services/):

> Right now, AWS doesn’t offer an option to make an advance payment.
>
> However, some individual AWS services offer payment options that are similar to prepayment. **For example, Amazon EC2 offers Reserved Instances, which allow you to pay an up-front fee to reserve capacity for your account in one-year or three-year terms.** For more information about the pricing models for various AWS services, choose that service’s pricing page from the list at [Cloud Services Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/pricing/services/).

There is no mention here of EBS.